# Save Drawing as Image

Tags: c#-3.0, drawing

How can I create a drawing on a form and then save the drawing as an image file?

Comment: You might want to add a bit more detail than that in order to get some help.

Comment: What did you use to do the drawing?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the code in this [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287529(VS.71).aspx).

And add Image.Save()

Answer (score 0):

Image.Save?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx